# How to convert a string into Image and print that image in a bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: android, zebra-printers

In my application when i click print button print will come from the Bluetooth printer, right now i am able to print the data...

But suddenly i recognize that this (Zebra MZ320 printer) doesn't support Hindi language.

i need to print Hindi data also in the printer , so the only option i have is Convert the string(Hindi) data into image and then printing that image.

For that i need to know how to convert an string into image and also i don't want to save that image whenever printing is completes then i want to delete it...

Can any one guide me how to acheive this , i already started with Base64 encoding and decoding but not succeed(means how to do).
i am using the below code to convert my string into image but i am getting Skimage Decoder--Factory returned null

```
String cpclConfigLabel = "Purchy No:";
             byte[]  configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes();
             Log.e("Befire Bimta",""+configLabel);

             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(configLabel , 0, configLabel .length);
```

for every valuable reply i will give kudos....

Comment: nice app idea..if find any code please let me know..

Comment: Dear Frankenstein just inform me if you have any idea about converting string into image remaining i can do...

Comment: I dont know..but I have seen something like this..is this can be useful to you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763667/create-bitmap-image-from-edittext-its-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Thermal printer Arabic Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909331/android-thermal-printer-arabic-issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Base64Encoder.java](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/Base64Coder.java.txt) or for [2.2 onwards this](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

You can render the text to a TextView and save that into a bmp

Like so:

```
View viewToBeConverted;
// do stuff on the View    
viewToBeConverted.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = widget.getDrawingCache(true);
viewToBeConverted.destroyDrawingCache();
```

See: [`buildDrawingCache()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache%28boolean%29)

Comment: hmm Frankenstein is right, if you can render the text on the screen, you can get a bitmap out of the drawing cache. I'll look for other options.

Comment: i am using the below code but i am getting null in BitmapFactory      String cpclConfigLabel = "Purchy No:";
     byte[]  configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes();
     Log.e("Befire Bimta",""+configLabel);

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(configLabel , 0, configLabel .length);

Comment: If you can render hindi text on a TextView, you can print the image generated from that TextView on the printer.

Comment: ok but i am getting Illegal Argument Exception if i use below code  TextView viewToBeConverted = new TextView(this);
     viewToBeConverted.setText(cpclConfigLabel);
     Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewToBeConverted.getWidth(), viewToBeConverted.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
     viewToBeConverted.draw(canvas);

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android) could helps you