# Image printing with Zebra printer using escpos

Tags: android, iphone, image-processing, bitmapimage, zebra-printers

I am working on an application in which I need to develop functionality for image printing on zebra printers.
The printer we are using is Zebra EM220II printer.

Problem we are facing:

1) Currently we are using "GS V 0 m xL xh yl yH d1...dk" command as mentioned in the manual (http://files.gammasolutions.com/upload/pdf/em220II-command-ug-en.pdf).

However we with this command we are able to print images of certain size where some images are not getting printed.

2) We have also tried with "ESC * m nL nH d1...dk" command but there is not any success for that.

I have searched almost all the links some of them are here as follows:

http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/12/sending-a-bit-image-to-an-epson-tm-t88iii-receipt-printer-using-c-and-escpos/

[Printing an Image using a Bluetooth Thermal Printer From an Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982485/printing-an-image-using-a-bluetooth-thermal-printer-from-an-android-app)

[How can I print an image on a Bluetooth printer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android)

However I am not able to figure out any thing as the method mentioned in above links is using "ESC * m nL nH d1...dk" command.

Please let me know if any one can help on this as I am struggling since two weeks.

Let me know if any more details are required.