# Printing POS/ESC Apex3 image S.O.S

Tags: java, android, printing, bitmap, thermal-printer

I have an Apex3 and I have been able to follow most of [the documentation](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/sp/sp-sp/file.cfm/7A300007_Rev2.pdf) without problem, but when it comes to images things turns very weird (lack of examples + lack of consistency in how to do it).

First I try the naive approach of trying to pass a Bitmap byte[] array compress with JPEG and 0 quality since I did not mind, using the command:

ESC V n1 n2 data

That did not work out well.

Then I discover there is an android library for apex3 that accept a bitmap and supose to print it but it does not work just print weird symbols like this:

[image]

I try to decode the jar source using JD gui and they seem to do some work with the bitmap bytes this is their code (piece of advice code like addToDoc(m_Document, ESC + "B"); just put the code in a ByteArrayOutputStream the data), (decompiled [source from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/voxxuw0x8da13l0/do_androidsdk.jar)):

```
public void writeImage(Bitmap imageObject, int printHeadWidth)
    throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
    if (imageObject == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter 'imageObject' was null.");
    }
    if (printHeadWidth < 1) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter 'printHeadWidth' must be greater than 0.");
    }
    int height = imageObject.getHeight();
    int width = imageObject.getWidth();
    

    byte blanklineCount = 0;
    byte[] dataline = new byte[printHeadWidth + 7 >> 3];
    int[] imageData = new int[height * width];
    
    imageObject.getPixels(imageData, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    

    addToDoc(m_Document, ESC + "B");
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
      boolean blankLine = true;
      for (int index = 0; index < width; index += 8)
      {
        byte currentByte = 0;
        int offset = row * width + index;
        if (index >= printHeadWidth) {
          break;
        }
        int value = index + 0 < width ? imageData[(offset + 0)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        boolean set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? -128 : 0));
        
        value = index + 1 < width ? imageData[(offset + 1)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 64 : 0));
        
        value = index + 2 < width ? imageData[(offset + 2)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 32 : 0));
        
        value = index + 3 < width ? imageData[(offset + 3)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 16 : 0));
        
        value = index + 4 < width ? imageData[(offset + 4)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 8 : 0));
        
        value = index + 5 < width ? imageData[(offset + 5)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 4 : 0));
        
        value = index + 6 < width ? imageData[(offset + 6)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 2 : 0));
        
        value = index + 7 < width ? imageData[(offset + 7)] & 0xFFFFFF : 16777215;
        set = (value >> 0 & 0xFF) + (value >> 8 & 0xFF) + (value >> 16 & 0xFF) < 384;
        currentByte = (byte)(currentByte | (set ? 1 : 0));
        

        dataline[(index >> 3)] = currentByte;
        blankLine &= currentByte == 0;
      }
      if (!blankLine)
      {
        if (blanklineCount > 0)
        {
          addToDoc(m_Document, "A");
          addToDoc(m_Document, blanklineCount);
          blanklineCount = 0;
        }
        addToDoc(m_Document, compressGraphicLine(dataline));
      }
      else
      {
        blanklineCount = (byte)(blanklineCount + 1);
        if (blanklineCount == 255)
        {
          addToDoc(m_Document, "A");
          addToDoc(m_Document, blanklineCount);
          blanklineCount = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    if (blanklineCount > 0)
    {
      addToDoc(m_Document, "A");
      addToDoc(m_Document, blanklineCount);
      blanklineCount = 0;
    }
    addToDoc(m_Document, ESC + "E");
  }
  
  private byte[] compressGraphicLine(byte[] dataline)
  {
    byte count = 0;
    byte currentByte = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream rleString = new ByteArrayOutputStream(128);
    

    addToDoc(rleString, "G");
    for (int index = 0; index < dataline.length; index++) {
      if (count == 0)
      {
        currentByte = dataline[index];
        addToDoc(rleString, currentByte);
        count = (byte)(count + 1);
      }
      else if ((count < 255) && (currentByte == dataline[index]))
      {
        count = (byte)(count + 1);
      }
      else
      {
        addToDoc(rleString, count);
        count = 0;
        

        currentByte = dataline[index];
        addToDoc(rleString, currentByte);
        count = (byte)(count + 1);
      }
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      addToDoc(rleString, count);
    }
    if (rleString.size() > dataline.length + 1)
    {
      rleString.reset();
      addToDoc(rleString, "U");
      for (int item = 0; item < dataline.length; item++) {
        addToDoc(rleString, dataline[item]);
      }
    }
    return rleString.toByteArray();
  }
```

But I don't get why it is not working.

Finally I try to use **[How can I print an image on a Bluetooth printer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android)** with the same algorithm as a guide but still printing random weird symbols.

Comment: My guess is you can't print an image to a monochrome printer its not in the POS printer protocol for that printer.

Comment: I like to disagree in the printing test there is an image logo, so I would say it's possible

Comment: I wish I knew more so I could help more, I haven't programmed a POS printer in years.

Answer (score 2):

instead of wasting time with decompiling some apk, why not having a look in the offical SDK? On the manufacturer webpage [Downloads & Drivers](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/home/support-downloads/downloads-drivers) there is a link to the [Java SDK](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/file.cfm/sdk_java_v2_1_0.zip?contentID=5990&ext=.zip) which includes a source `Sample.java`. In the source an `BufferedImage` is created so I guess (I don't own such a printer) this will give you an entry point for your problem. And most probably they provide on the same page the source for the Android demo [Printer Demo Source code for Android](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/file.cfm/DOPrinterDemoSourceForAndroid.zip?contentID=6316&ext=.zip)

**edit** Ok. Let's summarize: You have an image and want to print it. In the example Sample.java this case is covered

```
  BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(1024, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
  // some lines and rectangles are drawn in the image
  ...
  // the image is printed, following the SDK javadoc for DocumentLP.writeImage
  // "This will cause the image specified to be printed. Images will be expanded to occupy
  // the entire width of the printer, so the correct current width of the printer must be
  // specified. Images that are too wide will be cropped, and images that are too narrow 
  // will be padded on the right."
  testDoc.writeImage(newImage, m_PrinterWidth);
```

For me the only things you have to do:

- create an BufferedImage object
- draw your image from the file into the buffered image
- call the writeImage method of your DocumentLP object

**edit 2** pseudo code snippet

```
// taken from SDK javadoc
DocumentLP docLP;
docLP = new DocumentLP("$");

// own code
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(--from your image--);
BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(bis);

// have a look into Sample.java for the expected value of m_PrinterWidth
testDoc.writeImage(bufImage, m_PrinterWidth);
```

**edit 3** code snippet for Android (taken from the DO_AndroidSDKDemo_MainActivity.java provided with the [datamax o´neil Android SDK](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/file.cfm/DO_AndroidSDK_2_0_0.zip?contentID=7451&ext=.zip)

```
File file = new File(selectedPath);
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
InputStream inputStream= new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
inputStream.read(readBuffer);
inputStream.close();
fileData = readBuffer;

Bitmap m_imageObject = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
documentLP.clear();
ocumentLP.writeImage(m_imageObject, m_printHeadWidth);
```

Comment: because it does not work, it's the same decompiled and if you check the code what they do is draw it with a canvas I need to be able to sent a bitmap.

Comment: ok, let me clarify is android only, and the Sample.java is based on awt

Comment: BufferedImage does not exist in android,

Comment: @Necronet sorry this I have overlooked. But have a look in the **edit 3** example.

Comment: Thanks for the support +SubOptimal

Comment: @SubOptimal  You would expect edit 3 to be the solution, but their example program just prints garbage characters. I tried in my program with the same result.