# Print Image Via Bluetooth Printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I want to print image on bluetooth printer receipt but i am getting characters. I have tried basic logic that we apply to write image in external file.
here it is :

```
void sendData() throws IOException {



Bitmap imageBit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();

        image.setImageBitmap(imageBit);


        mmOutputStream.write(bitmapdata);
        // tell the user data were sent
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent");

    }
```

Here it is complete code please help me:

```
package com.example.bluetoothnew;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // will show the statuses
    TextView myLabel;

    // will enable user to enter any text to be printed
    EditText myTextbox;

    // android built in classes for bluetooth operations
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    String strPath = "/sdcard/transparent.png";
    byte[] buffer = null;

    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            // we are goin to have three buttons for specific functions
            Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
            Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
            Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
            myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);

            // open bluetooth connection
            openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        findBT();
                        openBT();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            });

            // send data typed by the user to be printed
            sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        sendData();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            });

            // close bluetooth connection
            closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        closeBT();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * This will find a bluetooth printer device
     */
    void findBT() {

        try {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
            }

            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                    .getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                    // MP300 is the name of the bluetooth printer device
                    if (device.getName().equals("EPX58P")) {
                        mmDevice = device;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Tries to open a connection to the bluetooth printer device
     */
    void openBT() throws IOException {
        try {
            // Standard SerialPortService ID
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

            beginListenForData();

            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * After opening a connection to bluetooth printer device, we have to listen
     * and check if a data were sent to be printed.
     */
    void beginListenForData() {
        try {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
            final byte delimiter = 10;

            stopWorker = false;
            readBufferPosition = 0;
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];

            workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                            && !stopWorker) {

                        try {

                            int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                            if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                    byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                    if (b == delimiter) {
                                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                                encodedBytes, 0,
                                                encodedBytes.length);
                                        final String data = new String(
                                                encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                        readBufferPosition = 0;

                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                myLabel.setText(data);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            stopWorker = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            workerThread.start();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /*
     * This will send data to be printed by the bluetooth printer
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    void sendData() throws IOException {

        Bitmap imageBit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, blob);
        byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();

        image.setImageBitmap(imageBit);

        // the text typed by the user
        // String msg =
        // "Hello fjgfh gjfhgjfhgf gjfgjhfj hgfhgjfh hgjfhgjf jhgfjghf" +
        // "gkjfgjkfgjfjkfgjfkgf\ndfdfdfddfd" +
        // "fdfdf" +
        // "";
        // msg += "\n";
        // mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.SET_LINE_SPACING_24);
        // mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
        // mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.SELECT_PRINT_SHEET);
        // mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        mmOutputStream.write(bitmapdata);
        // tell the user data were sent
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent");

    }

    /*
     * Close the connection to bluetooth printer.
     */
    void closeBT() throws IOException {
        try {
            stopWorker = true;
            mmOutputStream.close();
            mmInputStream.close();
            mmSocket.close();
            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type here:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/open"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/open"
        android:text="Send" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/send"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send"
        android:text="Close" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/close"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi I have similar problem. Did you find way how print image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print an image on a Bluetooth printer in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android)