# Adding image android drawable

Tags: java, android

I been working on a android project that print a image thru thermal printer. base on these post:

[How can I print an image on a Bluetooth printer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android)

http://code.taobao.org/p/printer/src/trunk/prtest/src/com/enjar/plugins/PrintTools_58mm.java

I able to accomplished that. but when i tried to re-size the image in the drawable folder and re-run the program i'm getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

I tried to replace the image, re-size and even make a new project, still i got this error

can anyone help me out? thanks in advance...

Comment: please post your log here.

Comment: 05-20 12:49:49.584 360-1003/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
05-20 12:49:49.584 360-1003/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found

05-20 12:50:01.213 360-1003/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'TIME_NS' not found
05-20 12:50:01.213 360-1003/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found

05-20 12:50:11.349 927-5285/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF