# How to print Large Image on Thermal Printer

Tags: java, android, thermal-printer

I'm able to print images on thermal printer. but the printed images has lines on in. i've googled it i did find some idea. like making it grayscale(bitmap i already done but no luck). i've seen the dithering but i cant make it work.

any idea/help is very much appreciated.! thanks MAN!

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the the answer here ... http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html