# printing an image on a Bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: android, arrays, printing, bluetooth

I am printing image below  via `Bluetooth` printer.

[image]

I m referring this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android#) for printing.
image size is 100 x 100 px and image mode is

```
public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte)255, 0};
```

but somehow it appears as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6RDw.jpg) . ive tried some options given in comments but its not working.

can anybody help me out?thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok working with this.

used 130x130 px image 
with single `mService.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);`

and image mode is
`public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte)255, 0};`

Reference -  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android)

Output image is

[image]

Comment: Hello. I have a some problem how can I set 130x130 px to image size?

Comment: @Faxriddin Abdullayev `bitmap.scale(130, 130)` in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use printooth library for any printer, printooth is simple and well documented,
https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth

```
var printables = ArrayList<Printable>()
var printable = Printable.PrintableBuilder()  
    .setImage(image) 
    .setNewLinesAfter(1) // To provide n lines after sentence
    .build()
printables.add(printable)
BluetoothPrinter.printer().print(printables)
```

Comment: Is there a way to print image with width morethan 256 px in Printooth?