# how to convert TextView into ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to convert TextView into ImageView so I will be able to save the ImageView as an image in the sd card.
How do I convert TextView into ImageView?

Thanks.
(I saw the other questions but them are not realy answer my question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this, by two ways.

You can create an Bitmap of any View using `buildDrawingCache()` and `getDrawingCache()`

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763667/create-bitmap-image-from-edittext-its-content) answer for further reference.

In the other way , you can take your whole rootview as a screen shot and you can save it into disc.

This will help to achieve the above [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Bitmap convertViewToBitmap(View view)  
{  
    view.measure(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    );  
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());  
    view.buildDrawingCache();  
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();  

    return bitmap;  
}
```