# How to move, rotate, and resize text by touch in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, rotation

I use GestureViews to rotate, crop, and move ImageView, but I can't use them to rotate , resize , and move TextView, because GestureViews classes only work with ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to convert the textview to imageview.

You can create an Bitmap of any View using buildDrawingCache() and getDrawingCache()

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

More details about the same are here - [Create Bitmap Image from EditText & its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763667/create-bitmap-image-from-edittext-its-content)

Then use touch gestures to drag and scale on-screen objects, using onTouchEvent() to intercept touch events. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale